# 13.10 Can't Adjust Dell Laptop Backlight

Tags: dell, 13.10, backlight

I have a Dell Studio 1558. When I originally installed 13.04 on it, I had to modify my `/etc/default/grub` with the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0 quiet splash"
```

Doing that made everything work, the keyboard brightness buttons, the OSD in the top right corner, and the brightness slider in System Settings. However, upon upgrading to 13.10, I once again am unable to adjust the backlight. This is also the case if I use either of the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

The backlight is stuck at a single brightness level, at a guess I think it's somewhere around 50%. The OSD still comes up if I push the keyboard buttons, but the bar only goes down one division from 100% and resets back to 100%, if I press decrease again. The slider in 'System Settings' does nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing both of the steps mentioned here fixed this issue with a Dell Studio 1558 and Ubuntu 13.10: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181534

## Change /etc/default/grub

I used "sudo vim /etc/default/grub" but use whatever editor you're comfortable with but you will need to use sudo to edit it as the root user.

From:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

## Add /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

I used "sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf" and then ran `:set paste` and hit `i` for insert and pasted in the contents.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Then reboot and login again and your function key with the brightness up/down should work again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in a terminal:

```
echo 4000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

4000 is the full brightness, and 0 is no brightness (screen completely dark), so you can choose any value in between as you like. Note that the path to the `brigtness` may be different on your computer, so adjust accordingly.

This works for me on Dell Studio 1558, Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. Also you'll have to do this every-time you have to change brightness. It will reset when you restart the computer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm as a workaround. I even setup keyboard shortcuts to invoke a bash script give me keyboard control.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use echo 4000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness because its giving me error like no file or directory found. Please help.