# Backlight issues with Asus X551MAV-EB01-B

Tags: 12.04, brightness, asus, backlight

I've got a fresh install of trusty (xubuntu if that matters, I don't think it should) on a Asus X551MAV-EB01-B.  My function keys for brightness don't work. Here's what I know so far:

If I pass `acpi_osi=` or `acpi_osi=!` to grub I can get the brightness and wifi keys to work (I know this because I can see the OSD for brightness change), **BUT**:

in `/sys/class/backlight` I have two items:

```
acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0
intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
```

With `cat` I can see the brightness keys are adjusting `acpi_video0/brightness` and not `intel_backlight/brightness`.

I've also tried passng `acpi_backlight=vendor` to grub, and if I do *that*, then I end up with *this* :

```
asus-nb-wmi -> ../../devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/backlight/asus-nb-wmi/
intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
```

`acpi_backlight=vendor` also stops the brightness keys from responding at all.

For now, I've set up an echo in `/etc/rc.local` to change the brightness a few seconds after lightdm starts... but where do I go from here?

Comment: Because in their infinite wisdom you can't PM on SO. How is trusty running so far for you? I'm leaving for a large trip and can't afford to bring any of my own expensive hardware. Was looking at laptops to bring just to sharpen some skills over some long plane flights and wanted to get your opinion on the X551MAV-EB01-B.

Comment: It's working rather well. I'm sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner; I forgot I had posted this question and I wasn't getting the notifications from Stack Exchange for some odd reason.  This hardware is better than average for the price and while I miss the built-in bluetooth from my previous system I have no complaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this (self-made) script for quite some time on my NVidia card and works fine. If @TheSchwa's solution doesn't work try this.

Install the script:

1. Open a Terminal
2. Type: `sudo apt-get install -y inotify-tools` and press `Enter`
3. Type: `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/backlight-sync` and press `Enter`
4. Copy the script from [this page](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wqJJcHLD) (has been adopted for your intel card already)
5. Paste it into the Terminal window using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V`
6. Press: `Ctrl`+`X`
7. Press: `y`
8. Press: `Enter`
9. Type: `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/backlight-sync` and press `Enter`

Test the script:

1. In the Terminal type `sudo backlight-sync` and press `Enter`
2. Change your screen brightness at least once to see if its working
3. Press `Ctrl`+`C` to quit

Enable the script during boot:

1. In the Terminal type: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and press `Enter`
2. Use the arrow keys to navigate above the line that says `exit 0`
3. Type: `/usr/local/bin/backlight-sync &`
4. Press: `Ctrl`+`X`
5. Press: `y`
6. Press: `Enter`
7. Close the Terminal window

Comment: I hadn't even considered using inotifywait/read to fix this issue. I like your solution though; it's both elegant and crude at the same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Dell Studio laptop, which also uses intel_backlight.  While I'm not sure if this will work on Asus, I think it's worth a shot.  See if the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight/401311#401311) helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Add to /etc/rc.local

echo N | sudo tee /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled

Reboot

Answer (score -1):

Try `video.use_native_backlight=1`.

Comment: This doesn't work. It still adjusts brightness under acpi_video0 and not intel_backlight.