# Hot keys brightness issues with Ubuntu 14.10 in Acer Aspire 5755

Tags: grub2, shortcut-keys, brightness, acer, 14.10

I have a Acer Aspire 5755 with Intel video graphic, on Ubuntu 14.04, the combination <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>(Right/left) arrows can increase/decrease the brightness screen. Works fine on unity and with a grub modification (boot flags `acpi_osi=Linux` and `backlight=vendor`) the hot key work on any desktop environment.

I make a direct upgrade to 14.10, and the hot key can not work, even with grub modification. But i can chance the screen brightness in System settings → Brightness and Lock.

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
intel_backlight
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I had the same problem on a Dell laptop that also uses `intel_backlight`, however for me the solution required getting rid of the boot flags.  See if [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/401311/205638) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I make some tests removing the grub flags. It doesn't work, but when I reintroduce the flags

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=vendor splash"
```

and run `sudo update-grub` the hot keys start to work again. Now I can control the screen brightness with key combination.

Answer (score 0):

I read a fix somewhere about that for Ubuntu 14.04.

Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Now you need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"EndSection
```

Save it. Log out and log in back

If it doesn't work simply go to usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and delete the 20-intel.conf file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add an upvote or a comment i'll just do a repeat of Rick's answer but now in a different laptop running ubuntu 14.04. Here's the set up

```
  Acer Aspire V5
  Ubuntu 14.04 (updated several times)
  Linux Kernel 3.13.0-52-generic
  Intel graphics card
```

All i had to do was to edit the default grub file in the configuration directory /etc and then update the grub a restart and everything was okay HOT KEYS are back (serious face)!. instructions

```
   Fire your terminal >> **CTRL + ALT + T**
   Enter the following command >> **sudo vim /etc/default/grub**
   (or any other text editor you like)
   then find the line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""** (if it's not there then create one below GRUB_TIMEOUT=""

   put the following boot flags to enable the hot keys >> **quiet acpi_backlight=vendor splash**

   so in the end you have the following >> **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=vendor splash"**
```

I beleive that this configuration will work for most Acer Computers that are running Ubuntu. Good luck!