# Can't control laptop screen brightness after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: intel-graphics, brightness, 14.10

My brightness is stuck at 100% when I have the power cord plugged in, and using the hot keys to change the brightness, or changing the brightness through the system brightness app does nothing until I take the level to 0 where the screen will go black. Bringing the brightness up one level from 0% will make the screen 100% bright again.

If I unplug the laptop, the screen goes to about 50% brightness (I don't know for sure, because the brightness setting still reads whatever it was set at before I unplugged it). Here again, the hot keys bring up the brightness indicator but the brightness of the screen doesn't change unless I take it to 0%.

I'm on a samsung series 5 ultra book with intel graphics. My brightness worked completely in 14.04.

I've tried the following fixes, but haven't had any success:

- Editing this file: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
  ([Upgraded to 14.10, brightness control quit working - Intel HD 4400](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541525/upgraded-to-14-10-brightness-control-quit-working-intel-hd-4400))
- Updating my grub config file
  (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144815)
  ([Hot keys brightness issues with Ubuntu 14.10 in Acer Aspire 5755](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541898/hot-keys-brigtness-issues-with-ubuntu-14-10-in-acer-aspire-5755))

Possibly related to this, steam games that ran perfectly are now super choppy and unplayable.

I've looked at the additional drivers app, but it doesn't list any additional drivers for my system. I've installed all updates as they've popped up.

Has anyone else experienced this, or found a solution outside of the two that I've mentioned?

Edit: Due to a hardware failure, I no longer have this laptop and due to this screen brightness issue among many others during the last 9 months using linux as my only os for work and home, I've given up on linux as a productive desktop environment (for my needs) again. I used this opportunity to purchase a mac rather than wasting more time fiddling with things that "almost, but not quite, but sometimes" work. /rant

Comment: See if the specific combination of `xorg.conf` and `grub` options in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/401311/205638) helps.

Comment: @TheSchwa I gave it a go, but didn't have any luck. My xorg.conf file was already set up that way, and I only needed to comment out the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in my grub config, since the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX value was already empty.

Comment: @rmmoul you should not comment out that line

Comment: @mchid, I tried it with and without the line commented out. The upgrade to 14.10 just caused too many issues, and trying to restore to 14.04 from backups caused my wifi card to not be recognized post-install (worked fine during the install process), so like I mentioned in my edit, I trashed the samsung and bought a macbook because I needed to get work done.