# Dell Inspiron laptop 17 7000 - brightness function keys Fn-F11 and Fn-F12 not working

Tags: dell, brightness, 18.10, inspiron, function-keys

The function keys to control the screen brightness - <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> & <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> - are not working.

Xubuntu 18.10.

Dell Inspiron 17 7000 (7786) laptop

I have tried updating the boot parameters in /etc/default/grub

Currently running:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi=Windows 2015""`

I also tried these options:
`"acpi_osi="`
`"acpi_osi=Linux"`

Some more checks:

```
ls -l /sys/class/backlight
```

...shows nothing.

```
xrandr --verbose | grep Bright
```

...shows nothing.

```
sudo showkey
```

...shows 224 for <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> (brightness down) and 225 for <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> (brightness up).

The other function keys - volume, keyboard backlight, wireless on/off, etc... are working OK.

Comment: Have you tried using F11 and F12 only? If yes, then you can turn it back previously used Fn+f11/fn+f12 by pressing Fn+Esc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

Taken from:

[Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)

and

[13.10 Can't Adjust Dell Laptop Backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight/401311#401311)

...but not the same.

**1. Create file: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

Open terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save the file and close nano.

**2. Update Grub settings**

In a terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line starting with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

and add the option "acpi_backlight=vendor" (without the quotes).

E.g.: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save the file and exit nano.

In a in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your laptop and it will work probably...